# How to know what is the pangkat of branches i am selected?

Tags: php, mysql

```
        <label>Branches</label>
                  <br>
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                  <!--
                  document.write('<textarea class="form-control" style="resize:none;" id="area" rows="3" readonly="readonly"></textarea>')

                  function updateArea (e) {
                  document.getElementById('area').value = '';
                  for (var i=0; i<e.form.elements.length; i++){if (e.form.elements[i].type == 'checkbox' && e.form.elements[i].checked) {document.getElementById('area').value += e.form.elements[i].nextSibling.data; document.getElementById('area').value += '\n';}};
                  }

                  // -->
                  </script>
                  <p>
                 <div class="form-control" style="float:left;
                      height: 100px;
                      overflow: auto;">

                        <?php

                        $select = "SELECT * FROM branches WHERE access = 'User'";
                        if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $select)){
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                          $brid = $row['brid'];
                          ?>
                          <input type="checkbox" name="brid[]" value="<?php echo $brid; ?>" onclick="updateArea(this)"><?php echo $brid; ?>
                          <input type="hidden" name="pangkat" value="<?php echo $pangkat; ?>">
                          <br>
                          <?php
                        }
                      }

                        ?>
                  </div>
```

here is the code i am selecting brid from branches table i already know how to insert multiple rows of selected branches to database i want to know how to insert the pangkat of branches am i selecting.

```
<?php 
require '../db/db.php';

$smsid = $_POST['smsid'];
$brid = $_POST['brid'];
$pangkat = $_POST['pangkat'];
$smssubject = $_POST['smssubject'];
$smscontent = $_POST['smscontent'];
$smsfrom = $_POST['smsfrom'];


for ($i = 0; $i<sizeof($brid); $i++ ){

    $insert = $conn->query("INSERT INTO messages(sms_id,brid,pangkat,subject,message,from_brid,datesent)
                VALUES('$smsid', '".$brid[$i]."','$pangkat',
                '$smssubject','$smscontent','$smsfrom',NOW())");

        echo "<script>alert('The Message is successfully sent');</script>";
        echo "<script>window.location.assign('../load/amessages.php')</script>";
}?>
```

here is my action page to insert brid but the pangkat is always blank any help?

Comment: Did the `$brid` variable shows any data when you at least do some `echo` on it? Is `$brid` an `array` or just a single value because in your form it looks like an `array` while your last code it looks like having only a single value.

Comment: its an array then i use for loop to insert the variable in each row to database

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pangkat"? That is Tagalog https://www.tagaloglang.com/pangkat/ for what could mean one of four things: "section, division, article, segment". Can you update your post to be replaced by the actual word you meant to use? @James Just the words/text, not the code.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
require '../db/db.php';

$smsid = $_POST['smsid'];
$brid = $_POST['brid'];
// $pangkat = $_POST['pangkat'];
$smssubject = $_POST['smssubject'];
$smscontent = $_POST['smscontent'];
$smsfrom = $_POST['smsfrom'];

for ($i = 0; $i<sizeof($brid); $i++ ){

    $select = $conn->query(" SELECT * FROM branches WHERE brid = '".$brid[$i]."' ");

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){

        $pangkat = $rows['pangkat'];

    $insert = $conn->query("INSERT INTO messages(sms_id,brid,pangkat,subject,message,from_brid,datesent)
                VALUES('$smsid', '".$brid[$i]."','$pangkat',
                '$smssubject','$smscontent','$smsfrom',NOW())");

        echo "<script>alert('The Message is successfully sent');</script>";
        echo "<script>window.location.assign('../load/amessages.php')</script>";
    }
}?>
```

problem solved thanks!